# removing null data using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors, data-processing

Am using scrapy to scrape data off a certain website, but the scraped data are full of null values I don't want so in order to clean my extracted data I have changed the pipeline.py script. and it worked when I extract a single value or two it works like a charm. but when I extract multiple values and since there is at least one null value on each extracted row the algorithm ends up deleting almost all my data. is there a way to stop this from happening ?

here is the code i used to remove the null data

```
class ConfigSpiderPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['task_id'] = task_id
        if col is not None:
            if not(all(item.values())):
                raise DropItem()
            else:
                col.save(item)
                return item
```

Comment: Could you share an example item that gets dropped against your wishes?

Comment: for example i have a document with an id a title and a caption , if either the title or the caption are null the method i used above ends up deleting the whole document , and since most the docuemnts have null values in them i end up scraping empty results

Comment: Use `spider.logging.debug('<message>')` to debug what’s going on. Is DropItem raised under unexpected circumstances? Is `col` ever `None`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to drop items that have all values as None, you should use 'any' instead of all:

```
class ConfigSpiderPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['task_id'] = task_id
        if col is not None:
            if not(any(item.values())):
                raise DropItem()
            else:
                col.save(item)
                return item
```

Or more clearly:

```
class ConfigSpiderPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['task_id'] = task_id
        if col is not None:
            if any(item.values()):
                col.save(item)
                return item
            else:
                raise DropItem()
```

Comment: i tried using this but intead of it removing only the items that have all values as none it droped everything when i scraped mutilple item and it didnt remove the null values when i scraped a single value

Comment: Probably your problem lies somewhere else then, as this pipeline does nothing more than saving the item when there is at least 1 value in the dict, and drops the item only when all values are null. Maybe provide the code of the spider itself as well

Comment: i have put in an other question with more informations here including my spider file and items file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61535398/removing-null-value-from-scraped-data-without-removing-entire